# FileProvider not work in android 8.1 and higher

Tags: android-intent, rx-java, android-external-storage, android-fileprovider, fileprovider

This is my code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "PacMe", pdfCreate);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }


public Disposable zipMethode(ContentLoadingProgressBar progressBar,PDFView pdfView,RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return Observable.zip(createPdf(), showPdf(progressBar,pdfView,recyclerView).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
            observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()), (o, o2) -> true)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe();
}

<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="pacMe"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>

<paths>
<external-path
    name="external_files"
    path="."/>
```

The program works properly, but does not work in android 28 and higher.

What is the problem?

I have been involved for a long time.

Comment: Can anyone help me???

Comment: Can't anyone help me?

Comment: I have been involved in this for a long time

Comment: Do you think it will work if I change compileSdkVersion to 27?